# Use pydev as a non-root

Tags: eclipse-plugin, pydev

I am using archlinux. I just installed the latest Eclipse (used pacman) and manually installed pydev (downloaded the zip file and upzip them into /usr/share/eclipse/dropins). The problem is that when I run eclipse as root I can see the Pydev plugin, but when I run eclipse as a normal user it seems that Pydev isn't loaded.

I am wondering how to fix this?

PS: I know I should have used Eclipse's update manager to install pydev. But since I am in China currently, many foreign sites including sourceforge are not accessible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hmm. Very strange. When I run as a normal user, Pydev does show up as installed. However, window->preferences do not have a configuration section for Pydev. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, but are the permissions available for your user to access what you've put in the dropins?

Also, just as a note, to install PyDev using the update manager see: http://pydev.org/download.html (note that that part has nothing to do with sourceforge).